# How to choose between variations of EfficientDet

Tags: deep-learning, tensorflow, object-detection

In the Tensorflow 2 Object Detection API [model ZOO](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/tf2_detection_zoo.md), there is 7 versions of the EfficientDet:

[image: versions]

Being new to deep learning, I don't understand very well what is the difference and how to choose the best one for my application (detecting buildings from satellite imagery). I haven't been able to find much info on this online.

**Question:** How do these differ and how does one decide which one to choose?

Answer (score 1):

Each of the networks have different architectures. You can see the architectures of each on page 6 of the [original paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1911.09070.pdf).

Some rough generalizations are:

- The lower numbered versions works best with low resolution images and the higher ones.
- The lower ones are faster, but less accurate.
- The lower ones requires less compute power than the higher ones.

So it's a trade-off that one will have to make depending on the use-case.